# How to declare global base url on RIDE in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

On RIDE editor there are 5-6 test suites. Each test suite opens the same URL after opening browser. I want to use a global variable (base URL )for those test suite. Could you please help me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

[[image]]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to delcare it as global  by using

```
  *** Variables ***
@{url}            Set Global Variable    www.google.com

*** Test Cases ***
test1
    log to console    ${url}
```

it's BuiltIn's Library.

Comment: Thank You. There are 3 variables types of Robot RIDE. Could you please advise, where I will declare it? How to write it in RIDE.

Comment: @sujit  *** Variables ***
@{url}            Set Global Variable    www.google.com

*** Test Cases ***
test1
    log to console    ${url}  Please find in my answer . i edited

Comment: I want to declare Global variable above test suite. I followed your provided code, But error found "Variable '${base_url}' not found."The attachment may be seen from this link:https://www.screencast.com/t/1CwDf7fj6idn Please advise.

Comment: i suggest you to create one *.robot file that's can be declare your variable . then you just call the keywords to your testcase . , https://snag.gy/xPya16.jpg  ,  https://snag.gy/p2zl9B.jpg    
   ,  https://snag.gy/PW6xEd.jpg  . please find my screenshot and i hope this solution will can help you

Comment: @SidaraThank you,I am using RIDE editor for robot framework. Could you please give an example with details on how to add or create a resource file on RIDE editor. Also, how to call keyword for multiple test suite. I want to execute multiple test suite by declaring a global variable (base_URL}, without declaring a variable on each test suite. Is it possible Sidara KEO .Thanks.